# Align HubSpot form horizontally

Tags: javascript, css, forms, hubspot

I would like the HubSpot form to align horizontally like below. I have used the embed code feature in hubspot which basically links to there JavaScript.

[image: out of box hubspot form & what i would like]

I tried fiddling around with these paramaters http://designers.hubspot.com/docs/cos/hubspot-form-markup but am not having any luck.

Comment: Please add your HTML/CSS or create a fiddle

Comment: This is the form that is embedded into the html

<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js"></script>
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({ 
    portalId: 'XXXXXXX,
    formId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
  });
</script>

Comment: First step is to remove the default HS styling. http://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/forms/how-do-i-style-my-embedded-form After that, follow the Dom model and apply the CSS classes you need (like display: inline-block answer below)

Answer (score 1):

Start with this link to learn the ins and outs of customizing the HubSpot Form Embed code: http://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/advanced_form_options

Your unstyled form JS will look something like this:

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js"></script> 
<script> 
    hbspt.forms.create({
        portalId: 'XXXXXXX',
        formId:   'XYZXYZXYZXYZ',
        css: '' // <-- Intentionally empty string! 
    });
</script>
```

Providing an empty string for ***css*** will prevent the snippet from loading the default hs-form stylesheet.

Congrats! You can now override the unstyled content with your own CSS stylesheet. In your own sheet, define the classes that you need mentioned here in the Designer docs: http://designers.hubspot.com/docs/cos/hubspot-form-markup#styling-forms

If we're missing the mark and you need help with defining your own CSS classes, let me know.

Comment: Awesome that helped out tremendously. For some reason when i copied out of hubspot it did not include the css portion. That is fixed so I am seeing a big difference. The only thing I cannot make happen is moving the form field (hs-input) to be horizontal with the submit button (hs_submit) using display inline block?

Answer (score 0):

Making assumptions on the element names since I can't see your code. But this will do the trick.

```
label,
button {
  display: inline-block;
}
input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: The elements would be here: http://designers.hubspot.com/docs/cos/hubspot-form-markup

Comment: I didn't feel like trawling through that mess to figure it out when you are familiar enough with your code to match it up.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by adding CSS to the particular Field and button
"display:inline-block;" or "float:left;" will work by providing width to the labels